# Repackaging an installed application with libraries included

Tags: packaging

I have a package installed in Ubuntu-13.10, called "GPIV", which is not available for Fedora, which I use in my lab for some unavoidable reasons. But, I want to use the GPIV software on Fedora also. Is is possible to repackage the installed GPIV executable as a tar ball, which also include all the linked libraries that the GPIV utilizes when it runs on Ubuntu. The idea is to extract the tar ball on Fedora and run the executable without installing. Since the tar ball already contains all the required libraries, it should run on Fedora too.

I remember about one such utility, but forgot the details. I did google check also, but no use.

If anyone has some idea, please let me know. It would indeed be very helpful. Will the SuperDeb Creator serve the purpose?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [alien](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/alien) to convert between package formats:

```
sudo alien --to-rpm gpiv_0.3.0-1_i386.deb
```

Don't use `--scripts` with this package; its scripts just run a [Debian-specific command](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/update-menus) that can be safely ignored.

If that package doesn't work in Fedora, you'll have to seek support from the Fedora community to either fix the RPM or compile Gpiv from source.